# How is the Spark select-explode idiom implemented?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assume we have a DataFrame with a string column, `col1`, and an array column, `col2`. I was wondering what happens behind the scenes in the Spark operation:

`df.select('col1', explode('col2'))`

It seems that [select](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#select(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) takes a sequence of `Column` objects as input, and [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) returns a `Column` so the types match. But the column returned by `explode('col2')` is logically of different length than `col1`, so I was wondering how select knows to "sync" them when constructing its output DataFrame. I tried looking at the [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html) class for clues but couldn't really find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple - there is no such data structure as `Column`. While Spark SQL uses columnar storage for caching and can leverage data layout for some low level operations columns are just descriptions of data and transformations not data containers. So simplifying things a bit `explode` is yet another `flatMap` on the `Dataset[Row]`.

Comment: Thanks! my question was technically about data frames, but I'm guessing it's much the same there. Here's [an example of this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0-rc1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1587-L1604) from the Dataset.scala source.

Comment: `DataFrame` is a `Dataset[Row]`.